# laravel carbon formatLocalized() generate three letter month date format

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using carbon and laravel 5.5 and want to format a date to only show the month in three letter format

```
(ie: 
    January => Jan, 
    February => Feb, 
 ...)
```

I've used the 'M' format but it doesn't work. this is my code:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse("2018-03-20")->formatLocalized('%M').
```

It returns

> "00".

Any idea please?

Comment: For now I'm going with this: substr(Carbon\Carbon::parse("2018-03-20")->formatLocalized("%B"), 0, 3) but if someone find a more proper way

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Carbon's `formatLocalized('%d %B %Y')` returns entire month string for 3 letter month name use it like this:

```
echo Carbon::parse("2018-03-20")->formatLocalized('%d %b %Y');
```

> OUTPUT
> 20 Mar 2018

Read more about [Localization](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)